# Always On Availability Groups Network Configuration in AWS

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, aws, network

I have set up a 3-node, multi-subnet Always On Availability group in AWS, which seems to be working well. However, each node only has a single network adaptor with 3 IP addresses assigned to it (1 primary, 1 WSFC IP resource, 1 listener). Is this sufficient for high-availability, or do I need additional networks? I believe with a traditional cluster you would need multiple networks & adaptors to ensure there is no single point of failure. I'm not sure if this is the case in AWS, as I assume they have redundancy built-in at their end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In AWS EC2, you don't get the ability to add additional network ADAPTERS to your VM.

You can add additional network INTERFACES, which are just different IPs/subnets/routes/etc, but they're using the same underlying network adapters (cards).

You can choose to use instance types with faster networking ports, though. The [EC2 instance configuration page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-ec2-config.html) lists which ones have 10 Gigabit ports, although I like [ec2instances.info](http://www.ec2instances.info/) for easier sorting and filtering. When you're doing Always On Availability Groups, it's especially important to use this faster networking because high-network operations (like backups to another machine) can [result in SQL Server timeouts](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/10/sql-server-timeouts-backups-checkdb/) (disclaimer: that's my blog post) if you've only got GbE networking. (That causes AG failovers.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Brent, that's great info. So I assume adding additional interfaces/routes would have little or no benefit then?

Comment: Correct, not if you run into the situations I describe above.